# 'Move and size with cells' is Greyed Out

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I added a form control checkbox using the developer tab, but the `Move and size with cells` option is greyed out.

[image]

I cannot find any information relating to Excel 2010 or greater that explains how to activate this option.

How can I enable this option?

Comment: The possible mistake you have committed is, you have selected the `CheckBox control` from the `Form Controls List`  you need to pick it  from `ActiveX Controls`. Then you find the `Move and size with cells` is not greyed out !!

Comment: Form Control's checkbox cannot be change size, this is by design.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a mistake, you have to treat that as an object, go to Format Shape, select the button with the right button and in Properties, you'll get the option.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the checkbox and go to the Format menu (top center)
Click on the small arrow available near the size option. this will open the panel on the right side. Click on properties and there you have this option to move and size with cells.
hope this helps.